# Java - Continuously check if input is a double

Tags: java, input

So, I've been a little stuck on this method I'm working on.  Basically, I need the method to take in input, check if it's actually a number, then see if it's between the max and min.

The problem I am currently having is when I ask the user to enter a new number, since their input was before 0 or greater than 1,000,000.  When the user enters anything other than a number it crashes.  Any ideas?

If you decide to show me how to fix it with a Try/Catch statement; would you tell me exactly how it works? I'm not 100% sure how those work yet!

**The code has been edited with the latest version**

```
public static double inRange( Scanner scan, int min, int max ) {
    double Amount = 0.0;
    boolean isValid = false;

    while( isValid == false ) {
        if( scan.hasNextDouble() ) {
            Amount = scan.nextDouble();
            if( Amount > max ) {
                System.out.print( "Error: You cannot enter a number greater than $1,000,000. Try again: " );
            }
            else if( Amount < min ) {
                System.out.print( "Error: You cannot enter a negative number. Try again: " );
            }
            else {
                isValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.print( "Error: You must enter a number! Try again: " );
            scan.next();
        }
    }
    return Amount;
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it crashes". What is the error?

Comment: @Blorgbeard here is a picture of the input I put in, and then it crashed the program.  http://gyazo.com/94e04444c5bb8318022a09fcc199394f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the bug is in these lines

```
if( scan.hasNextDouble() ) {
    ...
} else {
    System.out.print( "Error: You must enter a number! Try again: " );
    Amount = scan.nextDouble();  // problem is here, remove it!
}
```

If the scan has no next double, how can it get the next double value?
Besides, I think this line

```
Amount = scan.nextDouble();
```

should change to this

```
scan.next();
```

These are my codes, and they work fine.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int min = 0;
int max = 1000000;
double Amount = 0.0;
boolean isValid = false;

while (isValid == false) {
    if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
        Amount = scan.nextDouble();
        if (Amount > max) {
            System.out.print("Error: You cannot enter a number greater than $1,000,000. Try again: ");
        }
        else if (Amount < min) {
            System.out.print("Error: You cannot enter a negative number. Try again: ");
        }
        else {
            isValid = true;
                }
        }
    else {
        System.out.print("Error: You must enter a number! Try again: ");
        scan.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed that, and it went into an infinite loop.  Trying to fix atm.. The loop kept looping "Error: You must enter a number! Try again: "

Comment: Try adding `scan.next();` in place of the `nextDouble` you removed.

Comment: @Blorgbeard is right! 
Add scan.next(); instead of Amount = scan.nextDouble();

Comment: @MarkL I did what you said, and replaced 'Amount = scan.nextDouble();' with just 'scan.next();'.  While I have been getting somewhat more successful results I am still getting one.  It will catch input that is not a number, but I had some odd output.  Here is a picture:http://gyazo.com/8e5fa0b93c3d05608fcb49cb02ee4c06

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a couple ways to fix this and a few ways to improve your code.

So the problem is that a Scanner returns a string and you are assigning that String to a double which is ok when it is something like "23" or "2.4" but doesn't work with "Hello". 
You do a good job to check if the String has a double at the beginning

```
  if( scan.hasNextDouble() )
```

but you don't check if it has a double in the else

```
 else {
        System.out.print( "Error: You must enter a number! Try again: " );
        Amount = scan.nextDouble();
    }
```

so if a user enters a `String` like "Hello" it says Scanner `scan` doesn't have a `double` and then tells the user but assigns `Amount` equal to the next thing entered without checking if it is a double. So if you enter "Hello" again it will crash. But if you remove that line like someone suggested you will get an infinite loop because if you look at [the documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextdouble.htm) for `hasNextDouble`  it says that "The scanner does not advance past any input." which means that it will keep checking the same thing you entered unless you move the scanner along. So you need to do something to move the scanner along like `scan.nextLine()` which returns the String just entered and you could use that to give the user more info like 
`System.out.print( "Error: You must enter a number! " + scan.nextLine() +" is not a number. Try again: " );`

So if you enter "Hello" it will tell you that Hello is not a number.

Also the [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) is that variables are named starting with a lower case so instead of `Amount` use `amount`. Also you could make your code a little more modular because right now although min and max are variables which can be changed you are always telling the user that they are 1,000,000 and 0. So if I put the max as 2 and then entered 3 the program would tell me

"Error: You cannot enter a number greater than $1,000,000"

If you change that line to 
`System.out.print( "Error: You cannot enter a number greater than $" + max + ". Try again: " );`
it will make more sense.

Yes you could fix the original issue by using a try catch to catch a `InputMismatchException` but this answer is already quite long and you can read about that [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy reply.  I appreciate it.  And yeah I normally don't name my variables with capitals, but for some odd reason my fingers just wanted it to be capital.  I ended up solving the issue, and it lied with a 'scan.next();' in the method this method was called in.  So, I removed that and it is no longer asking for second input.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue.  I had a 'scan.next();' in a method that calls my inRange() method.  So, once I removed that my issue of it asking for input twice was solved, and the method successfully checks if it is in fact a double.

```
    public static double deposit(double bankAcc, String pinCode, Scanner scan ) {
    boolean valid = false;
    double depositAmount = 0;

    System.out.print( "Please enter your PIN #: " );
    String pinCodeTest = scan.nextLine();

    while( valid == false ) {
        if( pinCodeTest.equals(pinCode)) {
            System.out.print( "How much would you like to deposit?: " );
            depositAmount = inRange( scan, 0, 1000000 );
            valid = true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println( "Error! Incorrect PIN #. Try again: " );
            pinCodeTest = scan.nextLine();
        }
// I had a 'scan.next();' right here... Thinking it acted as a buffer clear!
    }
    return depositAmount;
}
    public static double inRange( Scanner scan, int min, int max ) {
    double amount = 0.0;
    boolean isValid = false;

    while( isValid == false ) {
        if( scan.hasNextDouble() ) {
            amount = scan.nextDouble();
            if( amount > max ) {
                System.out.print( "Error: You cannot enter a number greater than $1,000,000. Try again: " );
            }
            else if( amount < min ) {
                System.out.print( "Error: You cannot enter a negative number. Try again: " );
            }
            else {
                isValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.print( "Error: You must enter a number! Try again: " );
            scan.next();
        }
    }
    return amount;
}
```